# How to check if the input matches the value in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, javascript-objects

```
this.wiredUserData =
  [
    {"result":
    {"fields":
    {"Id":{"value":"005xx000001X85BAAS"},
     "Username":{"value":"emily@gmail.com"}}}}, 
    {"result":
    {"fields":
    {"Id":{"value":"005xx000001X7sHAAS"},
     "Username":{"value":"kristina@gmail.com"}}}}
  ]

const uid = "005xx000001X85B"

usernameData(uid) {
    if (this.wiredUserData) {
        this.wiredUserData.forEach(function (item) {
            let wiredUserId = item.result.fields.Id.value.slice(0, 15);
            console.log(wiredUserId, "wired");
            console.log(uid, "uid");
            let wiredUsername = item.result.fields.Username.value;
            if (uid === wiredUserId) {
                return wiredUsername;
            }
        });
    }
    return '';
}
```

I am attempting to return the username value (e.g. kristina@gmail.com) when the function is called if the uid and Id match.

Hi, I am looping over `wiredUserData` and getting an error Expected to return a value at the end of function. What am I missing here? Should I use another kind of for loop ?

Comment: `wiredUserData?.find(item => item.result.fields.Id.value.slice(0, 15) === uid)`? But it really looks like you should refactor your data into a more usable shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `.forEach` functional loop when you want to return something.

Either you can do this

```
function usernameData(uid) {
  if (!this.wiredUserData) return;

  let tempResult = '';

    for (const data of this.wiredUserData) {
      let wiredUserId = data.result.fields.Id.value.slice(0, 15);
      let wiredUsername = data.result.fields.Username.value;
      if (uid === wiredUserId) {
        tempResult = wiredUsername;
      }
    }
  
  return tempResult;
}
```

or this

```
function usernameData(uid) {
  if (!this.wiredUserData) return;

    for (const data of this.wiredUserData) {
      let wiredUserId = data.result.fields.Id.value.slice(0, 15);
      let wiredUsername = data.result.fields.Username.value;
      if (uid === wiredUserId) {
        return wiredUsername;
      }
    }
  
  return '';
}
```

or this

```
function usernameData(uid) {
  if (!this.wiredUserData) return;

    for (const data of this.wiredUserData) {
      if (data.result.fields.Id.value.slice(0, 15) === uid) {
        // use null aware operator for more checking 
        // like data.result.fields.Username?.value ?? '';
        // can use in other example of above as well.
        return data.result.fields.Username.value;
      }
    }
  
  return '';
}
```

Thanks, if anything else or it is still not working comment on it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return out of forEach statements (use a for loop instead):

```js
const wiredUserData = [{
    "result": {
      "fields": {
        "Id": {
          "value": "005xx000001X85BAAS"
        },
        "Username": {
          "value": "emily@gmail.com"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "result": {
      "fields": {
        "Id": {
          "value": "005xx000001X7sHAAS"
        },
        "Username": {
          "value": "kristina@gmail.com"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

const uid = "005xx000001X85B"

function usernameData(uid) {
  if (wiredUserData) {
    for (const item of wiredUserData) {
      if (item.result.fields.Id.value.slice(0, 15) === uid) {
        return item.result.fields.Username.value
      }
    }
  }
  return '';
}

console.log(usernameData(uid))
```

Answer (score 0):

Especially if the idea is to do this operation repeatedly and/or on a larger array, it would serve you to index the userData by the user ids...

In other words, if there was an index that looked like this...

```
// say there was a prop called userDataIndex...
userDataIndex = {
  '005xx000001X85B' : { /* the object with the 85B id */ },
  '005xx000001X7sH' : { /* the object with the 7sH id */ },
  // ...
}

// lookup method
userWithUid(uid) {
  return this.userDataIndex[uid];
}
```

...the username method would be as simple as this...

```
usernameData(uid) {
  return this.userWithUid(uid)?.username;
}
```

So all that's needed is the `userDataIndex` prop.  This can be computed when the `wiredUserData` is set. One idea would be to do that in a setter...

```
set wiredUserData(wiredUserData) {
  this._wiredUserData = wiredUserData;
  this.userDataIndex = wiredUserData.reduce((acc, el) => {
    const id = el.result.fields.Id.value.slice(0, 15);
    acc[id[] = { ...el, username: el.result.fields.Username.value } ;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

get wiredUserData() {
  this._wiredUserData
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use Array.find() if you know the structure of the JSON in your array.

```
const result = this.wiredUserData.find(element => element.result.fields.Id.value == uid);
```

This will return any object whose result.fields.Id.value matches the uid provided, or undefined if none match. You can also use Array.findIndex() with a similar callback if you need the index of the result.

ref:
[Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
[Array.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Answer (score 0):

As per your condition, You will get `emily@gmail.com` and not `kristina@gmail.com`.

Also, You can simply achieve this requirement with the help of [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`String.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const wiredUserData = [{
        "result": {
            "fields": {
                "Id": {
                    "value": "005xx000001X85BAAS"
                },
                "Username": {
                    "value": "emily@gmail.com"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "result": {
            "fields": {
                "Id": {
                    "value": "005xx000001X7sHAAS"
                },
                "Username": {
                    "value": "kristina@gmail.com"
                }
            }
        }
    }
];

const uid = "005xx000001X85B"

const wiredUsername = wiredUserData.find(({ result }) => {
    return result.fields.Id.value.includes(uid);
});

console.log(wiredUsername.result.fields.Username.value);
```